# more of a ... vs more a

Tags: prepositions

What's the difference between these types of adjective usages?

For example:

> This is more **of** a prerequisite than a necessary quality.
>
> This is more a prerequisite than a necessary quality. (without "of")

Comment: To me they sound identical

Comment: Ok - but when we faced by this question in test which choice is best ??

Comment: If these two options show up in a test, then the test is poorly written. They're both 100% natural, and both somewhat informal. If this is a test as part of a course, then give the answer that you were directly taught during the course, because that's probably what the writer of the test intended. If it's just a standardized test, like an entry exam, then I've got nothing for you. Both are such casual expressions, that it doesn't make sense to choose one as "more correct" than the other.